# CodeFirst cannot create database on shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I want to deploy Entity Framework 5.0 to Shared Hosting.

Now I have the problem with database. I cannot create database.

```
<add name="ResContext" 
connectionString="Data Source=XXXX5.db.10232343.hostedresource.com;
Initial Catalog=XXXX5; User ID=XXXX5;
Password=XXXXXXXXX!;Integrated Security=false"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"></add>
```

First
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

I got the problem

> Cannot drop the database 'XXXX5', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

But when I change provideName to

providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

> Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

Comment: when/where do you see it? Is it in the debugger?

Comment: @Pawel Yes it is in Debugger.
I run it on localMachine to test Is it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically GoDaddy does not give you permission to create or drop databases programmatically.  They only allow you to create those databases through their user interface.  This is because they don't want people creating databases all over the place, and they want to ensure that only you have the rights to access the database in a shared user environment.

So you cannot use the default generation method that EF uses.  Instead, you would use the Database initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have breaking on exception turned on. This exception should be handled and you should be able just to press F5 to proceed. You will probably see a few (5 or so) exceptions like this. This is how EF is probing whether the database you want to work with exists, is up-to-date etc. You can also just change the setting - go to "Debug -> Exceptions..." and uncheck the checkbox in the "Thrown" column on the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" line.

Comment: Also enabling "[Just My Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/25/understanding-just-my-code.aspx)" in the debugger settings should hide these exceptions that are thrown (and caught before getting to your code) in other libraries.